# Application Insights from last Debug session

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm encapsulating `TelemetryClient` functionality to a framework component for both client and server to use. In the process, trimming dependencies and replacing default behavior with my own.

My problem, however, is although telemetry shows up in debug output, it's not shown in the *Application Insights Search* window.

[image: AISearch]

Note, the telemetry is picked up in Azure Portal.

How can I get data from debug session telemetry, without the full blown Web App to *Add Application Insights Telemetry...* workflow?

Steps to reproduce:

- Create Azure resource, replace `InstrumentationKey = "###YourKey###"` in snippet below
- Create .NET Framework ConsoleApp
- Add Microsoft.ApplicationInsights nuget package

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Track.AddEvent("Debugging");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Search Insights");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class Track
    {
        private static readonly TelemetryClient TelemetryClient;

        static Track()
        {
            TelemetryConfiguration config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            config.InstrumentationKey = "###YourKey###";
            TelemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(config);
        }

        public static void AddEvent(string eventName)
        {
            TelemetryClient.TrackEvent(eventName);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Taking data from Azure Resource.

[image: AzRes]

Comment: I see you have a `ReadLine()` in there, but does calling `Flush()` on the telemetry client before the program exits make a difference?

Comment: @Brendan I did a flush before the Console calls, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what caused it, but you can get around by manually adding `ApplicationInsights.config`.

Workflow:

- Right click project: Add new item...
- Choose: Application Configuration File
- Name: ApplicationInsights.config

Running the solution again made the event count appear next to the light bulb.

- Go to *Application Insights Search* window
- Check *All*
- Update

*Data from Debug session telemetry* shown accordingly.

Funny thing, if you now remove the config file, the events will still show up in the *Application Insights Search* window, although the count next to the light bulb disappears again.

Comment: it's too weird. But it's good you solved it. You can mark it as answer, and may help others.

Comment: This works for .NET Core apps as well. The config file can be empty, it just has to exist to coerce Visual Studio into displaying the telemetry.

Comment: This doesn't work in VS 2022 (at least last time I tested it).

Answer (score 1):

I just copy your code and install the latest version of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights(2.9.1), works fine at my side: I can see the telemetry data is shown in the "Application insights search".

1. So can you confirm the version of the visual studio? Seams that there is [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/235717/application-insights-search-does-not-show-telemetr.html) in some previously visual studio version . I'm using 15.8.5, and works fine.

[image]

2. Can you confirm the time range you select is correct?
3. Please check if you can see the count of telemetry data in your visual studio as per screenshot below:

[image]

4. Also, if there is an update button, please click it to get latest data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time. To be sure, I upgraded to latest (v15.9.7), but no cigar (1). Note that the _Application insights search_ window does get populated with data when I switch to the Azure resource, it just doesn't for data from _last Debug session_. In neither case I get the telemetry data count next to the light bulb (3). Points (2)&(4) checked.

Comment: Do you mind explain more about " it just doesn't for data from last Debug session"? I'm not very clear or misunderstanding. thanks.

Comment: When data is taken _from last Debug session_, no telemetry is shown (first screenshot). Though it works fine when data is taken _from the Azure resource_ (added screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

I had been unable to solve this problem for some time. This problem is still present with Visual Studio 2022, but the accepted answer ("Add an ApplicationInsights.config file") doesn't work (in VS 2019 or VS 2022).

I had tried a number of other approaches including Visual Studio tooling for adding a "Connected Service Dependency" on Application Insights SDK (Local), which seems like it should work.

[image: Connected Service Dependency Screenshot]

It adds `Properties/serviceDependencies.json` and `Properties/serviceDependencies.local.json`, which look like they tell Visual Studio that the project uses App Insights, but still no data when debugging in the App Insights window.

After searching around on this problem again, I [found a fix here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/application-insight-doesnt-show-logs-from-local-de/1240506). Add the following to the .csproj file being debugged:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Needed for Visual Studio to "see" local App Insights data in debug output. -->
    <ApplicationInsightsResourceId>dummy-value</ApplicationInsightsResourceId> 
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This works even with no dummy `ApplicationInsights.config` file, and without the `serviceDependencies.json` file; and the presence of those files does *not* work.

Comment: that's a bit strange

Comment: Don't forget to restart Visual Studio after modifying the .csproj.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that by default, Application Insights nuget uses `appsettings.json` [independently](http://%20https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/e2731fee82d9dbbe052a3b00ce5def95ed64c8f2/NETCORE/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/Extensions/DefaultApplicationInsightsServiceConfigureOptions.cs#L15) of your `IConfiguration`. Which is silly IMHO.

If you don't use `appsettings.json` files, your local AI will not capture your telemetry information. You can add empty `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json` into your project folder...

...or you can remove the configuration registration and/or add your own. Local AI telemetry will start working after that.

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

// remove default AI config that reads appsettings.json
var invalidAiDescriptor = services.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ServiceType.Equals(typeof(IConfigureOptions<ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions>)));
services.Remove(invalidAiDescriptor);

// re-configure with your own IConfiguration object if you want
services.Configure<ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions>(configuration);
```

Comment: As of 2.15, it should read from `IConfiguration`: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/commit/e6635a227c14eba75037e1b2d6b62a04cdacf05a#diff-2a4de3ef8e203bdf87ac759c67de5efab1a77e92f671a4da6f8257b3d1caf153R35

The fact that it adds `appsettings.json` it still bad.